# Writing into a file without overwriting

Tags: python, shell

I'm trying to get a programme of mine to write its output to a file. It does this in a loop, but I think that it overwrites what is in the file each time, instead of adding to it. Here is the relevant code:

```
g = open('mjd.txt','a')

for i in range(len(new_y)):
    os.system('vap -c "mjd" {0} > mjd.txt'.format(new_y[i]))
```

where vap is the command from another programme which outputs one line.

After looping though, there is only one line in my "mjd.txt" file, and I want there to be several.

Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: You might also want to have a look at `subprocess` as a nicer alternative to `os.system` (there you can bypass the shell altogether).

Comment: also the `g = open('mjd.txt','a')` line is not needed here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the line to the following to append. Can't think of what the name of the > and >> are at the moment.

```
os.system('vap -c "mjd" {0} >> mjd.txt'.format(new_y[i]))
```

Comment: > redirects stdout, overwriting whatever it's redirecting to.  >> appends via stdout.

Comment: `>` (right chevron) is redirection. `>>` (double right chevron) is redirect with append.

Comment: @Makoto thanks. Redirection operator was the term I was trying to think of.